# PHP <-> Java Socket random empty packet

Tags: java, php, sockets, tcp

I am working on a project that requires a PHP web application to reach a Java server through TCP sockets. Everything seems to be working fine, besides one small detail: there is always an empty packet if specific steps are taken (which are listed below the code)

I'm not sure what the cause is and it's the first time I make sockets between two different languages talk to each other and the first time to use them in PHP in general as well, so my code is probably not ideal.

Here's the code:

These are the functions to send and read packets in PHP

```php
function sendPacket($message) : void {
    if (!$this->connected && Config::get('debugging')) {
        echo("Cancelled packet send as we are not connected.");
        connectionFailed("There has been an error. Please, contact the administrators.");
    }
    socket_write($this->socket, $message."\nend\n") or
        connectionFailed("There has been an error. Please, contact the administrators.");
}

function readPacket($length = 15) : string {
    if(!$this->connected) {
        if (Config::get('debugging'))
            echo("Cancelled read as we are not connected.");
        connectionFailed("There has been an error. Please, contact the administrators.");
    }

    $line = socket_read($this->socket, $length, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
    if (substr($line, -1) === "\r")
        socket_read($this->socket, 1, PHP_BINARY_READ);

    if (str_ends_with($line, "\n"))
        $line = substr($line, 0, strlen($line) - 1);

    return $line;
}
```

This is what I then use to send the server a token and retrieve a response

```php
public function isUserTokenValid(string $userToken) : string {
    $this->sendPacket("user:validate-token:$userToken");
    usleep(500 * 1000); // I've tried to put this here in case it was a delay issue, but it wasn't
    $response = $this->readPacket();
    return $response;
}
```

Here's the Java code I use to read packets

```java
private String readPacket() throws IOException {
    StringBuilder packet = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null && !line.equals("end")) // in is a BufferedReader
        packet.append(line);

    return packet.toString();
}
```

And here is what I use to send packets

```java
private void sendPacket(String content) throws IOException {
    if ((!isConnected()) || out == null)
        return;

    System.out.println("OUT> " + content); // This is for debugging and proves that a value is being sent.
    out.println(content); // Out is a PrintStream
    out.flush(); // I've tried both flushing and not flushing, it doesn't change much
}
```

After reading the packet I split it and then parse it.
This is what is going on behind the scenes before I send the `user:validate-token:$userToken` packet:

1. PHP sends a packet telling the Java server to authenticate and gives it a token
2. The Java server checks the token and tells the PHP server whether it's valid or not (dropping the connection if the latter)
3. PHP then sends a packet with username and hashed password to the Java server
4. The Java server checks whether the information is valid and if it is returns a token
5. Finally PHP sends the packet to validate the token
6. The Java server sends back 1 if the token is valid, 200 if it isn't

Every single step before the token validation (5) goes fine.

A var_dump of the result, though, shows `string(0) ""`, consistently.

Skipping step 3 and 4 results in everything working fine.

But if step 3 and 4 are executed reading the packet twice (so using $response = $this->readPacket() twice) does indeed work and read the number correctly.
Although reading twice when step 3 and 4 are not executed makes the Java server hang.

If I haven't been clear enough or more code is needed, please let me know

Comment: I'm not certain, but I noticed that you're using `out.println()` on the Java side.  This will append a newline character after the data, which could be tripping you up.  Are you certain you meant to include a newline there?  And can you try it with just `out.print()` and see if the problem goes away?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I have tried out.print() but then the PHP server doesn't seem to understand that the packet has been received - basically it sends the authentication packet, doesn't recognize that it's received a packet and never sends the next one
EDIT: Which is because I'm using  PHP_NORMAL_READ, which reads until new lines (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-read.php)

Comment: What is the OS of the Java server?

Comment: You lead me to the right way. I replaced PHP_NORMAL_READ with PHP_BINARY_READ (which is like Java's InputStream#ready) and replaced out.println() with out.print(), now everything works flawlessly

Comment: I have fixed the issue, but both PHP and Java are running on PHP. I have also posted an answer describing how I fixed my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my issue also thanks to markspace's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68732703/php-java-socket-random-empty-packet?noredirect=1#comment121470392_68732703).

They suggested trying to replace `out.println()` with `out.print()`, which I had already tried but, unfortunately, lead to nothing but PHP hanging.

But then, reading more into PHP's `socket_read`'s parameters I understood that `PHP_BINARY_READ` (which is also the default mode) does the same as Java's `InputStream.ready()`, basically reading until it figures there is no input left (which was exactly what I needed, actually), whereas `PHP_NORMAL_MODE` reads until it finds a new line character (`\r` or `\n`).
So, replacing `out.println()` with `out.print()` in Java and `$line = socket_read($this->socket, $length, PHP_NORMAL_READ);` with `$line = socket_read($this->socket, $length, PHP_BINARY_READ);` in PHP completely fixed the issue.

I did also uncomment out.flush(), but I'm not sure whether that makes any difference.

Thanks again, markspace, for helping me figure this out!